# Making ordered lists in Wordpress' advanced layout editor

Tags: wordpress

When I make a list in the **Wordpress** text editor, like this

`<ol>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
</ol>`

and later switch to the **Advanced Layout Editor** (edit: this is specific to the **Enfold Theme**), it automatically turns into

```
<ol>
<ol>
<ol>
<ol>
    <li>first</li>
</ol>
</ol>
</ol>
</ol>
<ol>
<ol>
<ol>
<ol>
    <li>second</li>
</ol>
</ol>
</ol>
</ol>
<ol>
<ol>
<ol>
<ol>
    <li>third</li>
</ol>
</ol>
</ol>
</ol>
```

which is just silly with unordered lists, but defeats the purpose of an ordered list, as every item is its own list (within a list within a list).

Does anyone else have any experience with this? Or with getting around this?

If it's any use, I'm using **Wordpress 4.4.2** with the **Enfold theme (versions 3.0.4)**. 
The only plugins I'm using are **BackUpWordpress, Duplicator, and Velvet Blues Update URLs**.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the **Advanced Layout Editor**.  Is this just the *Visual Editor*? Or do you have a plugin you are using?....

Comment: I've looked into it; apparently it's an editor exclusive to the theme. That narrows the scope of my question quite a bit. I'll bother their support for a bit. Thanks for asking the right question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in that particular version of the 
Enfold theme. Updating it should help.